# closing pop up window on button click(if successcede) and reload parent window

Tags: asp.net, validation, popup

I am using this code.This pop up window pops up when I clicks a button on the main page.Now I want the pop up window to be closed if the password is successfully changed and reload the main page,but if the password is not changed then refresh the pop up window again.
I used javascript for form validation`enter code here`
Here is the code.....

```
<asp:Textbox id="curnt_paswrd" textmode="Password" runat="server" size="30" />
<asp:Textbox id="new_paswrd" textmode="Password" runat="server" size="30" />
<asp:button ID="btnChange" class="submit-button" 
          OnClientClick="return validate()" runat="server" Text="Change" 
          onclick="btnChange_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply like this: When you return **true** the main page automatically refreshes.

```
function validate() {
    var strOutput = window.showModalDialog('ChangePassword.aspx', null, "dialogWidth:750px; dialogHeight:190px; dialogHide:false; edge:raised; center:yes; help:no; scroll:no; status:no;resizable:no;");

    if (strOutput == undefined)
        return false;

    else if (strOutput == '') 
        return false;

    else return true;
}
```

On your popup page, in javascript:

```
function IsSavePasswordSuccess() 
{
    window.returnValue = '<%=hdnSaveClickStatus.Value%>';
    window.close();
}
```

The hidden field will be set as. It will be set in your C# method.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSaveClickStatus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the that popup you can do something like this in script if the change was successful:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
window.close();
```

So for example using [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "CloseScript", 
  "window.opener.location.reload(); window.close();", true);
```

Comment: where should I write the RegisterStartupScript??

Comment: @Andy - In the child page, as part of the success function, so in your `btnChange_Click` handler, *if* it was successful.